# Tkinter keybinding for Control-Shift-Tab

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling, tkinter, key-bindings

What's the key-binding for Control-Shift-Tab? I've tried lots of things and nothing seems to work. I'm already aware of tkinter.ttk.Notebook.enable_traversal.

If you know of a handler for tabs being activated, that would suffice, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general format for representing an event is:
<[event modifier(s)-]...event type [-event detail]>. 
For key-binding Ctrl+Shift+Tab the format would be:
'Control-Shift-KeyPress-Tab'. 
In this case the event modifiers would be:
Control-
Shift-, 
the event type:
Keypress, 
and the event detail:
-Tab

The following code (in python 2.7.6) should make it clear:

```
from Tkinter import *

def key(event=None):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+Shift+Tab'

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.focus_set()
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-KeyPress-Tab>', key)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: The above works well for Windows and Mac. For Linux, use

```
'<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>'.
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I tested your code and the same in my code. It's not working for me in either Python 3.4 or Python 2.7 on Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit (3.4 is what I need, though). Adding KeyPress didn't do anything. Binding higher widgets (like root, the Frame and the Notebook) didn't do anything. I believe, however, that <Shift-Tab> or <Shift-KeyPress-Tab> is being executed first. However, those won't bind, either. Binding the regular <Tab>, <Control-Tab> and <Control-Alt-Tab> works just fine. Plain <Alt-Tab> does not work, though (although I'm not looking to bind it).

Comment: I'll try it in Lubuntu and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tested on my mac and it worked fine. Make sure you execute the .focus_set() method before binding. If the widget doesn't have the focus, it won't respond to the bind. Try replacing the bind() function by bind_all(), this will let you use the same binding across all windows and widgets of the application. Post some code so I can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Good to know it works on a Mac. I was using your code (so, no need to repost it), and the focus was set in my code. I tested it in Lubuntu. And, it doesn't work there, either. Additionally, '<Control-Alt-Tab>' doesn't work in Lubuntu. Because '<Control-Alt-Tab>' does work in Xubuntu, I think this is a distribution/OS-specific problem that those who made Tkinter need to program around, somehow. I think your code is fine, and mine, too. It doesn't produce an error saying the key-bindings don't exist. So, that would indicate that they're supposed to be working, methinks.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, because it is right, even if it doesn't work on Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit (and Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit), although the KeyPress thing is optional.

Comment: Adding keyboard shortcuts in Xubuntu for a certain keybinding makes it so it doesn't work in my program. I'll have to look and see if I can disable certain ones for certain programs, somehow.

Comment: FYI... I also tested it in Windows7 and with python 2.7.5, 2.7.6 and 3.3.2. Don't know why that happens in Xubuntu. Cheers, keep going!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for testing those, too. Okay, I found the problem. Linux has different keybindings for Shift-Tab for some reason. I was looking for this: '<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>'. For just plain Shift-Tab, use '<ISO_Left_Tab>'. Since I didn't mention anything OS specific in my question, I'm just commenting instead of answering and switching the preferred answer.

Comment: I also wonder how to bind shift + number (e.g. shift-1). I tried <Shift-1> but it didn't work