# The Ctrl+Shift+a not working inTkinter bind_all

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to recreate the notepad. I have added a lot of shortcut keys with a combination of two keys. I am trying to make a three combination shortcut, which will be `Ctrl+Shift+s`. But when I used `<Control-Shift-Key-s>` it's not working. I had even tried `app.bind<Control-Shift-KeyPress-s>` which I found at the [Control+Shift+Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377819/tkinter-keybinding-for-control-shift-tab) key binding in stack overflow. When I used `Tab` instead of `s` that worked, when I use `s` nothing happens. I want to create a key binding of `Control+Shift+s`. How Can I Do That?
This Is My Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

def SaveAs(event):
    #Some code to save as new file.
    print('Pressed Ctrl+Shift+s.')

app.bind_all('<Control-Shift-Key-s>', SaveAs)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you are not mixing up uppercase and lowercase, because in Tkinter, `"<Control-S>"` means <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and `"<Control-s>"` means <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

So, this line:

```
app.bind_all('<Control-Shift-Key-s>', SaveAs)
```

must be

```
app.bind_all('<Control-S>', SaveAs)
```

Comment: Oh, I did not even think of `S` which is a combination of `Shift+s`. Thank you, this really is helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy that I helped you.